# Trying to make a realistic simulation of 'breaks' (Pool)

Tags: simulations, collision

I'm working on a 2D pool simulation project right now, and I'm trying to create good looking physics that are also performant.

After collisions are detected, I update the velocities of the balls. So far, I've assumed collisions are elastic, which gives pretty good results. The formulas for the final velocities of both balls after a 2D elastic collision are easy to find, and I can follow the derivations of them well enough.

The problem is that 'breaks' are not realistic: momentum is often passed along the top and bottom of the triangle of balls, and only the top and bottom corners fly off.

I was wondering if changing the equations to use partially inelastic collisions would make the break look more realistic. I would use a coefficient of restitution that is close to 1. However, I'm not able to find many examples of 2D partially inelastic collisions that give final velocities. I'm not sure if I can derive these easily myself, and I'm a bit short on time.

Would this approach be worthwhile? Will using slightly inelastic collisions give me the results I'm looking for? If so, are there any resources that can help me solve this problem?

Comment: What are your initial conditions?  Are you assuming the balls are all in contact with their neighbours?  This wouldn't be realistic.

Comment: The balls are spaced apart and not touching, but by a very small amount.

Comment: Perhaps a picture would help demonstrate what you're showing, but I will ask this -- what makes you think that is the physically incorrect answer? I'm sure in an idealized world (and possibly real life), if you line things up exactly the way you have them, you would get the response you're getting (assuming, of course, your equations and code are correctly implemented!)

Comment: Also, the results will depend on the quality of your collision detection routines and your physics model -- there will be rotational component generated by the contact of the balls away from their centers of mass. So without more details about what physics your model includes, we can't really help you decide if adding *more physics* in the form of inelasticity will help.

Comment: See http://www.real-world-physics-problems.com/physics-of-billiards.html

Comment: Also see http://ruina.tam.cornell.edu/research/topics/collision_mechanics/new_algebraic_rigid_body.pdf

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about programming fast realistic simulation / approximations of physical systems.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Perfectly centered break of a perfectly aligned pool ball rack](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/96090/perfectly-centered-break-of-a-perfectly-aligned-pool-ball-rack)

Comment: Based on that linked question (where a very realistic looking break is simulated), I suspect your collision model has a bit too much stiffness to it.

Comment: You guys are right, in that I simply didn't give enough information about the collision system. As dumb as it sounds, a solution that worked for me was to simply place all the balls with a tiny bit of randomness to their position. Seems obvious in retrospect, but thanks for the help and resources here!

Answer (score 0):

I think reducing elasticity is a great idea. This is also true for real collisions 1 on 1 ball. But it will certainly be close to elastic.

I think if you want to simulate "perfect" racks, this can be a great tool but it will always be harder to reproduce in real life.

I am looking to do something similar with 9 ball break to find new patterns and reproduce imperfections in the rack and see how it is affected. But for 8 ball, way to many balls to have perfect racks every time